# Get unique nearby cities with calculated distance

Tags: mysql, coordinates

My table `places` has the following columns:

`| id | name | city | state | lon | lat`

The places can be located in the same cities. I am trying the upgrade the following query to get the **unique** nearby cities:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  city,
  state,
  (3959 * acos(
      cos(radians(:lat))
      * cos(radians(lat))
      * cos(radians(lon) - radians(:lon))
      + sin(radians(:lat))
        * sin(radians(lat))
  )) AS distance
FROM contact_references
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

`Group By` throws the following error:

> [42000][1055] Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause
>   and contains nonaggregated column

that requires changing the `sql_mode`. Which I can not do on the production server (policy).

I also cannot use `DISTINCT` because **distance** is not unique. So, It's a complicated challenge that I can't solve for a week already. Does anyone have any advise where to dig in?

Comment: I don't understand, why does `DISTINCT (city)` not work?  Sure distance is not unique but you are trying to make sure that the cities are unique right?

Comment: You are right, I'm trying to get the unique cities, but `DISTINCT (city)` gives me the result with duplicated cities.

Comment: You did not mention which column(s) you grouped by (it's generally hard to find problems in code you do not add to your question), but I can imagine you use `group by city`, but kept `select id`. Now MySQL does not know which `id` you want from the potentially 107 ids that are inside a city (but you just want one row per city and/or which distance to which id. Neither do we. If you know which id MySQL shall choose, add that to your question, maybe (actually: certainly) there is a fix for it.

Comment: @Solarflare, You are almost right, I use `group by city, state`. But even when I take off the `id` from the select, `MySQL does not know which ` `lat` and `lon` to choose.

Comment: @Solarflare what is your solution?

Comment: You didn't really specifiy which value you need (if you remove `id`, you obviously have the same reasoning for lon/lat). You may want to try an aggregate function, e.g. `..., state, min(3959 * ...) as distance from ...`. Then for each city, the shortest distance will be used.

Comment: @Solarflare You saved my life. I did `min(3959...` and `GROUP BY city, state` and it solved the issue. Thank you!